# Testing differences between census and survey

Tags: t-test, survey-sampling, census

I am trying to compare voter turnout for two consecutive elections, one in 2015 and one in 2019. I have turnout data for several geographic locations and age and gender groups. The goal is to see if there is any significant difference in the same (geo, age, gender) groups across the two elections.
Turnout is expressed as a proportion of the number of actual voters over registered electors.

My first thought was to use Welch's t-test, however, there is a catch: 2015 data was estimated by random sampling, while 2019 data contains the whole population. As result, 2019 variance is very small, so all tests turn out as significant.

Another issue is that I don't know how to interpret N to standardize variance: for 2019 I have N actual observation, whereas for 2015 I should probably use the actual number of sampled observations.

Does anybody know of a method to compare census and surveys in different years?

Comment: If you truly conceive of the 2019 data as being "the whole population," then its variance is irrelevant in any statistical test.  Indeed, unless your $N$ values are very small, the entire question of statistical significance seems pointless.  Maybe you should refocus your analysis on characterizing the observed differences.

Comment: yes, I will drop the test.